# Subclass WKWebview crash on dealloc in iOS

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm writing an app using WKWebView framework. I declare a new class named CustomWebView inherited from WKWebView

```
@interface CustomWebView : WKWebView {
    id customObject;
}
@end

@implement CustomWebView

- (id)init {
   if (self = [super init]) {
       customObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {

   //Doing my dealloc stuff
   [customObject release];

   [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I declare a new instance of CustomWebView on another UIView class

```
    cusWebview = [[CustomWebView alloc] init];
    cusWebview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cusWebview.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    cusWebview.UIDelegate = self;
    cusWebview.navigationDelegate = self;
    [self addSubView:cusWebview];
    [cusWebview release];
```

But when CustomWebView instance dealloc, it crashes on its dealloc method on line

```
[super dealloc];
```

just break on this line with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Can anyone know the reason

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be calling `[super dealloc]`

Also make sure you aren't adding observing any KVO's and not removing them in dealloc.

To be safe, I would also set your navigationDelegate and UIDelegate to nil on dealloc.

Comment: IIRC calling `[super dealloc]` on a ARC project is a compiler error. How the project did even compile?